# Why couldnt access the child class when child object reference is assigned to parent object pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a doubt regarding upcasting.
Consider there are two classes, Class Parent and Class child. Child has inherited with parent.

Question:

If i create object pointer for parent, and assigned child object reference. I complied it. the output is "object slicing". Couldn't access the child class specific components

```
class Parent
{
public:
    int i;

    void school()
    {
        std::cout<<"Parent Class::School()"<<std::endl;
    }
    // virtual goToPlay()
    // {
    //       std::cout<<"Parent Class::goToPlay()"<<std::endl;
    // }    

 };

class Child:public Parent
{
public:
    int j;
    void goToPlay()
    {
        std::cout<<"Child Class::goToPlay()"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Parent *mParent;
    Child mChild;
    mParent = &mChild;

    mParent->school();
    mParent->goToPlay(); //Error
```

couldnt access goToPlay() API. If i create a virtual function   of    goToPlay() in Parent Class, then its is accessible. Can any one tell whats the reason?

Comment: please refer to this link you will get all your answers..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c#274636

Comment: There is no slicing happening here.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Child specific components are not copied to mParent pointer object. So child object go sliced.

Comment: That's because it's a pointer, things don't get "copied to [a] pointer object". The pointer points to the base sub-object, the complete object is still a `Child` though. **There is no slicing happening here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly declare `Parent * mParent`, so your object is treated as an instance of `Parent`. In many use cases, this is exactly what you want - you provide a proper interface for doing something, and the concretely used implementation is of no concern to the end user:

```
class employee
{
    public:
        virtual double get_salary_in_usd() const = 0;
        virtual ~employee() {}
};

class software_developer : public employee
{
    public:
        double get_salary_in_usd() const { return 100000.; /* i wish */ }
        void be_awesome() {}
        ~software_developer() {}
};

void print_salary(std::shared_ptr<employee> const & emp)
{
    std::cout << "This employee earns $" << emp->get_salary_in_usd()
              << " a month." << '\n';
}
```

In some cases however, you need to tell at runtime, whether your pointer is a certain child of your base class. This is what `dynamic_cast` is for:

```
software_developer me;
employee * me_generalized = &me;

software_developer * me_again = dynamic_cast<software_developer *>(
    me_generalized);
if(me_again != nullptr)
{
    me_again->be_awesome();
}
```

Note that `dynamic_cast` can return `nullptr` if the pointer could not be casted. Also note that this happens with RTTI during runtime, and slows down your application. Avoid using this whenever possible.

Comment: So again we need to do downcasting to avoid object slicing?

Comment: @kayle This is always true when dealing with polymorphism. The trick is to design your application that it is not, or as little as possible, reliant on downcasting.

Answer (score 1):

Since your pointer type is `Parent` then only the Parent's api will be accessible since that is what you tell the compiler. (i.e. this pointer points to a `Parent` object).

In your case a `virtual` method will make the correct implementation being called. (this is called late binding and it is done during run time via hidden tables in the instance to find the correct address of the method's implementation which in your case is the `Child` implementation since `mParent` points to a `Child` instance)

Comment: yeah clear now. one more clarification. So assigning the derived class object reference to base class pointer is only to provide interface for virtual funcions?

Comment: @kayle: We cannot say why you did it. Perhaps you did it for some other reason.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Child::goToPlay()` through a pointer-to-`Parent`, `Parent` would have to declare its own function `goToPlay()`, and this function would have to be marked `virtual`. Your `Child` class then overrides that function.

Then, when you call `goToPlay()` on the `Parent` pointer, the `Child` function is magically invoked instead.

However, you can't just do this for arbitrary functions that doesn't even exist in `Parent`.